# Use the bandage automatically when I got shot?

Tags: urban-terror

Can anyone write a macro or is there any setting to do this automatically ?

I want to use the bandage automatically, when you got shot in UT4.1, I run Linux, so hot key software for Windows won't help.

Comment: I would note that while bandaging you can't shoot too, so sometimes it's better not to bandage immediately.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea, when shot you should try to find cover but keep shooting/covering your ass until you are in a safe spot.

Answer (score 1):

As said in others answers, you can't automatically run the action, since there's no *event trigger* and only *key binding* in Urban Terror configuration file (and Quake 3 in general).

It's not a good idea, but you can bind the bandage action on a extremely used key, like <kbd>MOUSE1</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>. This may brings some problems, because it's not very advised to medic you directly after a shot, and you may choose the moment of bandage yourself strategically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this automatically. You can, however, just press Q (or whichever key you have bound to bandage) after you get hit.